# Suggested itinerary for Bahia, Salvador, Brazil at Carnaval time?

Tags: brazil, itineraries, carnival-mardi-gras

Having been to Rio Carnaval in 2009, I would like to experience the equivalent in Bahia in Salvador, Brazil. Please suggest an itinerary to experience the Carnaval and other attractions.

A good starter for this is here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/4615/303

And I'd like further insight into people's experiences. Thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK then, I'll give this a crack and modify some schedules I've found in online tours.  It sounds fun.  I'll allow for about a week in Bahia:

Thursday 2nd Feb (this assumes 2012).  Arrive in Salvador, Bahia.  Check in, relax.

Friday - Go see the city.  There's a lot to see, and you'll start getting into the vibe for tonight. This night is the night of the Camarote Party.

Saturday - Was a big night! Time to relax at your hotel pool, beach, or see more the sights if you're a travel addict.  Try some of the local food, do a tour, or just explore with friends or people you've met.  Finally, head to the BLOCO. Party!

Sunday - It's beach day today.  Go check out some of Salvador's best beaches.  The best beaches in Salvador are located about 30 - 45 minutes from the city. It's a great way to relax amid all of the crazyness, get some downtime, and get a bit out of the main city.

Monday - If you didn't get enough of Camarote, tonight you could add All-Inclusive Camarote, which is one of Salvador's best features.

Tuesday - More sightseeing or relaxing, or if you still haven't had enough partying, choose if you want a CAMAROTE, a BLOCO.

Wednesday - all tuckered out? Head home!

This is adapted from [ToursGoneWild](http://www.toursgonewild.com/special-events/salvador-carnival-travel-package.html).

For further activity ideas and to get an idea of what to expect, the Brazil Nuts Tours blog has a great page on [Carnival in Bahia](http://brazilnutstours.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/carnival-in-bahia/).

Comment: +1 and accepted. I'm sure there might be more answers but I think this is a great starter, at the very least. Thanks very much @Mark Mayo.